# Linux Access point, but Android can't connect - says connection 'Saved'

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, wireless-access-point

I have a Dell Vostro laptop, and I'd like to create an Access Point. I followed the instructions in the 'readthedocs' howto. These are the steps:

```
$ nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name SecSpot autoconnect yes ssid SecSpot
$ nmcli con modify SecSpot 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
$ nmcli con modify SecSpot wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
$ nmcli con modify SecSpot wifi-sec.psk "12345678"
$ nmcli con up SecSpot
```

During testing, this gave some problems, as each succesive test created a new AP. I added a line at the start:

```
$ nmcli con del SecSpot
```

The result is an active AP, which I detect on my Android phone. But when I connect, with a correct password, I can't 'connect'. The phone says 'Saved', but no further. Signal is very strong - I'm at 50cm!

EDIT: To try another approach, I loaded the unsecure access point script from the same source:

```
nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name SecSpot autoconnect yes ssid SecSpot
nmcli con modify SecSpot 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli con up SecSpot
```

This enabled 'Obtaining IP address...' but no further.

Note that I visited dozens of sites with 'help'. So I tried many suggestions like 'forgetting' the connection, checking passwords, etc, etc.

I had the same problem with my previous laptop, go it working, but the machine died before I could make a backup of the script.

Any suggestions how to debug this?